# How to send Azure Function logs to blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have a working Azure Function and I added a few logs with log `(Ilogger instance)` and I can see them in the logs console in Azure Portal whenever I test the function or hit the function URL in via browser.

I want to send the same logs Azure Blob so I configured the,

**`Diagnostics Logs-> Application Logging (Blob) on -> Level Verbose -> Storage accounts settings set up to an existing storage account with container`**.

But I don't see my logs there. I see the folders generarted and logs written, but they are like just standard requests status messages like below:

```
2018-08-09T07:37:29,Information,TestFunction,cec757,636693970496377375,0,4860,6,Sending response: 200.0 OK,
```

What am I missing? I didn't see a way to add `addAzureWebAppDiagnostics()` call to `ILoggerFactory`. Please help!

Comment: When you said "I want to send the same logs Azure Blob so I configured", what are you configuring? Are you using the old logging system that uses Azure Storage with `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and wanting to store those logs inside of an Azure Blob instead of Azure Table storage..?

Comment: yes. What is the new logging system?

Comment: The new logging system is using [App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#monitoring-without-application-insights). App Insights offers a richer feature set of monitoring, and can increase performance by not having as much I/O to the storage account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the function logs are stored in Tables if using the old storage logging option, you should be able to access your logs using [storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/):

1. Visit the Function Portal.
2. Click on Function app settings-> Configure app settings
3. Locate the value for the App setting key AzureWebJobsStorage.
4. Extract the account AccountName and AccountKey values and provide them to Azure Storage Explorer

Your logs should be located in the table section. if that's the case, you can create a trigger function to move them to blobs if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: but the diagnostics logs setting only gives an option of selecting blob. So how does the functionapp know which storage account and which table to use to write the logs? Also when i check the tables section in my storage account linked to the azure function, is see table name and a URL something like : https://teststorageaccount.table.core.windows.net/AzureWebJobsHostLogs201808. When i hit that URL, i get an error "resource not found"

Comment: thanks! This helped! i was looking at Storage Explorer on the portal which is in Preview phase and hence was not showing up the tables, i installed Storage Explorer on my machine and connected to the storage and i could see my logs in the tables. Thanks again!